# Android Scrollview child background color flashes

Tags: android, android-layout, background, android-scrollview

I am facing a strange issue with scrollview as the child's background flashes when i scroll up/down. Important thing is that i have an edittext inside the scrollview. Also as per my visual design, i need to have the background applied to one of the child layout. For more clear understanding of this issue, i am embedding my layout code snippet below, hope could get a solution to this.`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#eeeeee" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/whitebg"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="44dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="800dip"
                android:background="@drawable/orangebg" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click to Next screen" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`

Note: Minimum android sdk is `android:minSdkVersion="14"`

Answer (score 0):

Change to this if it works, give transperent back ground to your scrolview's child linearlayout:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#eeeeee" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/whitebg"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="44dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="800dip"
                android:background="@drawable/orangebg" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click to Next screen" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: No yaar, it still happens, just click on the edittext once and then try scrolling, you could see the issue